# Battery thinks it's disconnected, even though it's not and the laptop is plugged in

Tags: 20.04, power-management, laptop, battery

Sometimes my laptop detects that the power cable is disconnected even though it's not. After some time it shuts down as if there is no charge even though it's plugged in; I always leave my laptop connected to wall power as the battery only lasts for 10 mins.

I was wondering if can I remove the battery management or power management package/software that deals with battery stats, health, ... to make it think that it's a desktop PC with no battery.

Would that work? How can I do it? Is there a better way to handle this situation?

Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS x86_64

Comment: This sounds like a combination of two things: (1) dirt (or corrosion) on the power connector (2) a battery that needs to be removed. Battery management is primarily done by the hardware, not the OS. You'll want to check that the metal parts of the power cord are properly clean. If you're using a Mac with a MagSafe connector, make sure all five of the pushpins are shiny. Also check where the power adapter plugs into the notebook to ensure it's clean and shiny. A partial connection may confuse the hardware and have it think the adapter is not connected.

Comment: In the mean time remove the battery it is not doing any good.

Comment: Ohh, I see thanks @matigo

Comment: thanks @David, ye i only kept the battery in case if there was a power cut, then the laptop immediately dies.